# Which is correct: Only I have access or Only me have access?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, personal-pronouns

Which is correct:

> Only I have access

or

> Only me have access?

I found similar questions but couldn't really figure out what is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember that "I" is used as a subject, and "me" is used as an object.
In your sentence "Only I/me have access," "I/me" is the subject. Following what I just said, you should use "I" as it functions as a subject.

Some people don't seem to know how to determine whether they're using I/me as a subject or as an object. The easiest way to know which pronoun to use is to remove the other parts of the sentence.

By removing "only" from your sentences, you'll have:

- "I have access."
- "Me have access."

The first definitely sounds correct, and the second sounds so wrong.

In another example: "You and I/me should not be late tomorrow."
Try using just each pronoun in the same sentence. You'll have:

- "You should not be late tomorrow." -- correct
- "I should not be late tomorrow." -- correct
- "Me should not be late tommorow." -- wrong

Answer (score 1):

Only I have access is correct.

I is a subject pronoun and is used when the speaker is carrying out an action or verb:

I ran the race.
I am learning Spanish.
I have a dog.